# In R 'factoextra',when i use function 'fviz_pca_var',how to change the label name?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I want to make the labels appearing with superscripts and subscripts.

I've tried function `expression` to change the colname of data.frame, it failed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HAse.png)

Answer (score 0):

One option to get your desired result would be to rename the columns of your dataset using `?plotmath` strings and setting `parse=TRUE` in `fviz_pca_var`.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `iris`:

```r
library("factoextra")
library("FactoMineR")

names(iris)[1:4] <- c("R[total]", "F[.<10*mm/d]", "P[.<=10*mm/d]", "T^{mean}")

res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)

fviz_pca_var(res.pca, col.var = "red", parse = TRUE)
```

[image]